# I need override a aw blog model

Tags: model, overriding, extension-methods

I wanna override the model post.php of a third part extension
the config.xml in the etension is like this

```
...
  <models>
            <blog>
                <class>AW_Blog_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>blog_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </blog>
            <blog_mysql4>
                <class>AW_Blog_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <blog>
                        <table>aw_blog</table>
                    </blog>
                    <post>
                        <table>aw_blog</table>
                    </post>
                    <comment>
                        <table>aw_blog_comment</table>
                    </comment>
...
```

The class I wanna override is here

AW -> Blog -> Model -> Mysql4 -> Post ->Collection.php

My class name is

```
class JC_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Post_Collection extends AW_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Post_Collection {
```

and is located here

JC -> Blog ->Model -> Mysql4 -> Collection.php

And my config is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JC_Blog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </JC_Blog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <aw_blog_mysql4>
                <rewrite>
                    <post_collection>JC_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Post_Collection</post_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </aw_blog_mysql4>
        </models>

    </global>
</config>
```

and the app/etc/modules/JT_ALL.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <JC_Blog>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <depends>
                    <AW_Blog />
                </depends>
            </JC_Blog>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

but dont works

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55194/overriding-third-party-extension-modules-model-not-working-local-on-local-overr

the correct config.xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <JC_Blog>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </JC_Blog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <blog_mysql4>
                <rewrite>
                    <post_collection>JC_Blog_Model_Mysql4_Post_Collection</post_collection>
                </rewrite>
            </blog_mysql4>
        </models>

    </global>
</config>
```